# How to add stored procedures to EF .edmx?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have a Mysql db and I cannot add stored procedures; I can see them in the update wizard but when I tick them and click save they are not added to the model.

Tried changing version of the connector as well as the version of entity framework yet nothing happens and I get no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it works but I had to tick off the "Import selected procedures and functions into the entity model" option and after the procedures were added I had to manually import the functions. I think EF was not able to import the result type for the procedures even though they were simple ones like scalars etc. yet there was no error / warning -.- .